# What are the available non-blocking web servers in D?

Tags: rest, webserver, d

What are the current choices for non-blocking servers available for D? Currently I have found two solutions: vide.d and mango servelets, but I'm not satisfied with the choices available. What have others used besides these two implementations of web servers?

Comment: set the socket for non-blocking and then poll each socket in the list

Comment: I've written an epoll thingy but no real web stuff on top. What specifically is the problems with the ones you've looked out?

Comment: I want something really basic, similar to Bottle in Python.

Comment: You won't find a better solution than VibeD, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this might be helpfull? https://github.com/csauls/zeal.d

Answer (score 3):

What is it that you miss with vibe.d for example. i am happily using it and it simply works. i am also writing an article series about exactly that and my experience with vibe.d: http://www.extrawurst.org/blog11/2014/01/stack4-and-the-d-programming-language-part1/

Answer (score 1):

I've not used it myself and therefore can't vouch for it at all, but I just saw this:

https://github.com/DannyArends/DaNode

Answer (score 0):

You can using [hunt-http](https://github.com/huntlabs/hunt-http) to build a webserver:

```
import hunt.http;

void main()
{
    auto server = HttpServer.builder().setListener(8080, "0.0.0.0").setHandler((RoutingContext context) {
            context.write("Hello World!");
            context.end();
        }).build();

    server.start();
}
```